# Generally, does the time it takes to compute (n mod m) depend on the size of n?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, arithmetic

Example:
Suppose I have a number *a* with 100 decimal digits, *b* with 200 decimal digits, and *m* with 10 decimal digits.

Would the speed of the computation *a mod m* vary greatly from *b mod m* because of the size of *a* vs *b*?

Comment: [Closely related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12931/complexity-of-taking-mod). [Probably related more general question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1643/how-can-we-assume-that-basic-operations-on-numbers-take-constant-time). Community votes, please: duplicate?

Comment: Also posted [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/compsci/comments/4l03z7/generally_is_the_size_of_n_a_factor_in_the_time/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You are doing long division. Whatever method you use, you will lose you a roughly constant number of digits per step, so there will be twice as many (well, about $\frac{190}{90}$ times as many) steps for $b$ as for $a$.

Answer (score 0):

In general it does, however, for certain special cases it will not.

A simple example is when $m$ is a power of 2. Then, the reminder is exactly the last $\log m$ bits of $n$, regardless of the size of $n$.